# How can I print from a list array Python

Tags: python

I am wondering how I can get print from a list array on Python, this is what I have so far;

```
op =  raw_input('Please enter a number: ')


lista = {"1":"cat",
       "2":"dog"}


for id, value in lista.iteritems():
    print id, value, op
```

Basically when you enter something in `op` (number 1 for example) it prints the id 1 from `lista`

the code `print id, value, op` prints the whole thing, and I know it does, that was only from testing the list array

Comment: http://docs.python.org/tutorial

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? How about `lista[op]`?

Comment: Recommend to read it all, but for a specific section: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: @TonyHarrison The technical name is a `dictionary`, not a `list-array`. It's the equivalent of a `hash-table` (`{key:value}`).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

`print lista[op]`

If your dictionary had integer keys however, you could simply translate `op` to an `int` such as: `lista[int(op)]`.

The reason your example did not work is because it iterated through the entire dictionary's K:V's and printed them.